# How to convert an array with 0(n log k)?

Tags: algorithm, converters

Input: Array A of n integers and k value (k<=n)

Output: 1D Array B

```
B[i]{ if i<k = 0 
      else k-th smallest number of A[1...i]
```

B should have the 3rd value from the minimum in A[1] to A[i], but if `i<k` the B value is 0

**O(nlogk)**

Example:

```
A: 2 -3 5 1 6
k=3
B: 0 0 5 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks for editing it to show the hidden text harold

Comment: Could you define array B more precisely?

Comment: I suspect this should have a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Shouldn't B in the example [0,0,-3,-3,-3]?

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary No, the array B given is correct. It contains the kth smallest number seen so far.

Comment: Smallest number seen so far in your case must be -3 and not 2. Also, then if `i == k`, copy the number to `B`. That is what `B` looks like from your post.

Comment: @user1990169 oh ok, then the case is that the algorithm goes from k to i, not 1 to i: A[k...i] not A[1..i] - I suggested an edit for the question to make it clear

Comment: @HarshGupta He doesn't want the smallest number seen so far. He wants the kth smallest number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the array maintain a max-heap containing k smallest elements seen so far.

Then scan the array from let to right and if the current element from array is less than the top-most element in the heap, then delete the top-most element and insert this new element (in log(k) time).

The array B shall be filled by the top-most element in the heap at each step.

In your example, initially heap is empty.

1. Scan 2. Heap contains 2, B[1] = 0.
2. Scan -3. Heap is now:
   ..2
   -3
   B[2] = 0.
3. Scan 5. Heap is now:
   ...5
   -3   2
   B[3] = 5.
4. Scan 1. Heap is now:
   ...2
   -3   1
   B[4] = 2.
   and so on..

Comment: @Adam If this answers your question, feel free to mark it as correct.